# Android: how do I check data change or not if I edit data in next activity and go back to previous

Tags: android, android-activity

i am trying to edit data form list and when I click on edit and go to next activity and update the data and go back to previous activity by starting new activity.
The problem is when i press back button it shows previous result.
On edit activity I use.

```
 finish()
```

Function to finish the edit activity.
How do i refresh previous activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {
     static boolean active = false;

      @Override
      public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();
         active = true;
      } 

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
         super.onStop();
         active = false;
      }
     @Override
     public void onResume() {
           super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first

       if (someflag == true) {
         // code to refresh activity
       }
   }
}
```

Set some flag to check on resume if true then refresh activity

Answer (score 1):

Create this function in your program, this is for rewriting your existing back button press.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,PreviousActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say if you're using a `ListView`, but let's assume so. In that case, in the first activity, you may need to add a line like `myListView.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onResume`. Otherwise, I think you're just getting back the first activity from memory (i.e., its state prior to the change in the data).

Answer (score 1):

When you open a new activity for editing you should use `startActivityForResult` like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1001);
```

And in the other activity when editing is done you should

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",true);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Then in the first activity you should override the `onActivityResult`

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1001) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //updated your listview here
        }
    }
}
```

This updates the listview if the data is changed